# SOAP service error

Tags: php, web-services, soap, nusoap

When I upload my webservice files to a live server it does not work. It was working on localhost. How can I fix this problem?

**Error message**

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing
>   WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'http://openinvite.biz/iphoneservice/server2.php' : Premature end of
>   data in tag html line 2 in
>   D:\Hosting\7340680\html\iphoneservice\test.php:102 Stack trace: #0
>   D:\Hosting\7340680\html\iphoneservice\test.php(102):
>   SoapClient->SoapClient('http://fomlatong.com/server.php') #1 {main}
>   thrown in D:\Hosting\7340680\html\iphoneservice\test.php on line 102

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use the WSDL version as opposed to the HTML one.

Change your URL to http://openinvite.biz/iphoneservice/server2.php?wsdl

The list of methods for that service appears to be

- syncvents
- getEvents
- getAllEvents
- searchPlaces
- rsvpEvent
- searchByCity
- EditEvent

I'm not sure why you expect there to be a `call()` method.

Comment: On adding wsdl at the end. I got this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("call") is not a valid method for this service in D:\Hosting\7340680\html\iphoneservice\test.php:116 Stack trace: #0 D:\Hosting\7340680\html\iphoneservice\test.php(116): SoapClient->__call('call', Array) #1 D:\Hosting\7340680\html\iphoneservice\test.php(116): SoapClient->call('syncvents', Array, 'uri:syncvents', 'uri:syncvents/s...') #2 {main} thrown in D:\Hosting\7340680\html\iphoneservice\test.php on line 116

Comment: @Chintoo See my updated answer. There doesn't appear to be a `call` method as part of that service

Comment: I know the methods all created by myself. 
I was calling these methods as:$client->call(
    'syncvents',                     // method name
    array('name' => $inpdata,'sender'=> 'sender2'),    // input parameters
    'uri:syncvents',            // namespace
    'uri:syncvents/syncvents'       // SOAPAction
);

Comment: Obvious problem, but hard to spot. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "soapclient" use "nusoap_client"